# Smooth function from $\mathbb R^n$ to a polytope

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, convex-analysis, polytopes

Given an open bounded convex polytope $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a way to construct a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose image is $C$?

For instance, if $C$ is the unit cube, we can use the logistic function in each coordinate; thus we can get any parallelepiped. If $C$ is a simplex, you can use the stick-breaking process. What other polytopes work?

I am actually interested in one particular polytope that comes from a problem in statistics. My polytope is entirely contained in the unit cube and its defining matrix is all 0's and 1's. I mention this just in case it proves relevant, even though I don't see why it would. I suspect if there is a solution for my case, then it would work more generally.

Would appreciate any leads!

Comment: Do you mean a a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Which definition of a polytope do you use?

Comment: Sorry, yes, $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Although a function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m>n$ could also help.

Comment: By convex polytope, I mean a system of solutions of linear inequalities. I guess I was assuming the polytope is $n$-dimensional, though again, a function from a higher-dimensional space would also help.

Comment: Do you want an explicit construction that you can actually use, or just a proof that such a function exists?  If you just want existence, then every convex (or even star-convex) open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb).

Comment: No, I want a function I can actually use! I guess I can try using that construction, but I think that's going to be too hard.

Comment: See also https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/papers/ConvexOpen.pdf.